# Phalcon ActionFilters

Tags: php, api, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I'm learning Phalcon (trying REST API in [multi-module](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/applications.html) application template), and I did simple checking for each request, "does this request contain specific header" for example `x-api-key` (something like ActionFilters in ASP.NET MVC).

1. I tried doing it with `annotations`, `plugins`, **`beforeExecuteRoute`**, and **`beforeException`**. But when I write in one of them `throw new \Exception("Some exception", 500);` then Phalcon returns a blank page without an exception message and code. AFAIK this is a known bug.
2. I tried to do it with the `dispatcher` in **`beforeException`**:

```
     public function beforeException($event, $dispatcher, $exception)
     {
        if ($exception instanceof \Phalcon\Http\Request\Exception)
        {
            $dispatcher->forward(
                    array(
                        'controller' => 'error',
                        'action' => 'showInternalServerError'
                    )
            );
            return false;
        }
        //...
      }
```

and it seems that's working, but this is not an elegant solution and I'm too lazy for this :)

**QUESTION**: Do you have any better ideas how to do ActionFilters in PhalconPHP?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the solution on [cmoore4/phalcon-rest/HTTPException](https://github.com/cmoore4/phalcon-rest/blob/develop/exceptions/HTTPException.php)

When the application throws an HTTPError this one modifies the response object to reflect the error details and headers and send it to the output.

I like the cmoore4 way of doing many things on the REST implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Match Callbacks in order to check for your api key:

Assume you have the following route:

```
$router->add('/api/v1', array(
    'module'     => 'api',
    'controller' => 'index'
))
```

You can prepend a check to it like this:

```
$router->add('/api/v1', array(
    'module'     => 'api',
    'controller' => 'index'
))
->beforeMatch(array(new AuthenticationFilter(), 'check'));
```

And in your custom created AuthenticationFilter, you are able to check for a valid api key:

```
<?php

class AuthenticationFilter
{

    public function check($uri, $route)
    {
        $response = new \Phalcon\Http\Response();

        if ($response->getHeaders()->get('X-Api-Key') != 'XYZ')
        {

            throw new CustomAuthenticationErrorExteption('Api Key Invalid');

            // you can also just return false here and redirect to a default non-authenticated 404 response

        }

        else return true;

    }

}
```

**Reference**

https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html#match-callbacks